# Interpreting Min-Max Scaled Regression Coefficients

Tags: linear-regression, scaling, minmax

Hi I am running a linear regression i.e. y on x. both variables are in units. I have scaled both variables between 0 and 1. In other words Min-Max scaling is applied on y and x. I am getting a significant coefficient value of 0.5. The question is what is the appropriate way to interpret 0.5:

1). 0.5 unit increase in y due to 0.1 unit increase in x?

```
                      OR
```

2). Since both y and x are between 0 and 1, can we interpret it in percentage terms i.e. 0.5% increase in y due to 1% increase in x?

Thanks for your comments and feedback.